# Wrong/Invalid Referrer is present in Request Header

Tags: html, node.js, express, browser, http-referer

I have 2 UI applications (node and ejs server side rendered).

Say
[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)

I redirect user from **Application A** to **Application B** using a simple button with href.

Now the Referrer in the Request header is Application A url which is expected.

Also after redirection to Application B. If the user navigates to the child pages, then the referrer is Application B url, which is also expected.

But the problem/issue is that from the child page of Application B, if the user clicks on **browser back button** then the referrer is Application A url which is not expected. Ideally the referrer should be application B since it's an internal redirection within the application.

This case is tested in Chrome and Firefox both behaves in a similar way.

I have to perform operation based on the right referrer. Please suggest a fix or correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Back button's function is to restore the previous page to the browser. That page arrived at the browser with its referer set to application A. So if the Back button does anything it's going to give you the old referer. That can't be changed. Because cybercreeps.

Your best bet is to handle the case some other way. For example, you could use [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to set some kind of browser flag saying you've already seen the first referer.